# About CSS issue

Tags: html, css

I have HTML And CSS like this below :

```
<style>
    .header_div{
        background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #F3F3F3;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #D5D6D6;
        box-shadow: 0 1px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.13);
        height: auto;
        left: 0;
        padding: 0;
        position: fixed;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: 50;
    }

    .content_div { width: 100%; }
</style>

<div class="header_div"></div>
```

Issue: Due to of this fixed position of header div some the postion of content div goes behind the header div. I dont want to apply margin to content div to solve this. because that affect other page designs also.And header div position is compulsory. So is there any alternative solution?

Comment: Generally people think that should be the way fixed divs should be styled, do you want your content to go over your fixed div :O

Answer (score 0):

I'm not even sure if I follow your question - an example would've been nice - but it sounds like you want a fixed header on some pages but don't want to push your content down because that would look weird on pages without the fixed header?

In that case, how about simply adding a class name to the content wrapper on pages woth a foxed header and apply margin to that? Like this:

```
<div class="header_div"></div>
<div class="content_div fixed_header"></div>
```

And then style it with:

```
.fixed_header { margin-top: 200px; }
```

Alternatively, if your markup allows it, target content_div only if it's a general sibling to header_div, like this:

```
.header_div ~ content_div { margin-top: 200px; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have different headers? The header would be the same on all pages right? So all content, or at least a div wrapping everything but the header could have a top margin to push it down. Why would you have content that *could* be over the header?

```
<div class="header_div"></div>
<div class="contentWrapper">

...everything else in here

</div>
```

Then push contentWrapper down. That's the proper way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `padding` instead of `margin` styling. It is the common way to prevent content overlapping:

```
.content_div {
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 20px; /*or whatever */
}
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/zbxvt/)**